# Why Can't My FB Test Users (Created Via Dashboard) Access the FB Page that Hosts My FB Messenger App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I've created them via the FB Developer's Dashboard, taking care to enable each's access to my app.

When I log in as the test user and attempt to navigate to the published FB page that hosts my FB chatbot, I get the error: "Sorry, this content isn't available right now. The link you followed may have expired, or the page may only be visible to an audience you're not in."

Docs say CLI tools are required to associate a test user with another app, but that (in my reading), the Dashboard works to grant access to the current app, including the page that hosts it.

Comment: Test users can not interact with real pages; if you want to test page-related stuff with test users, then you must login to Facebook as that test user and have it create a page first.

Comment: Hi @Cbroe I have the same question as above, but do you know if my test users can see test pages created by other my test users. My goal is to create 2000 test users and have them test a chat bot we've developed. thanks!